# Custom text field similar to 3DSMax's "user-defined properties"?

Tags: scripting, interface

I'm very new to scripting in Blender.

Is it possible to create a new UI element (specifically for Blender 2.9+) based on 3DSMax's "User-Defined Properties" window? This would be used in conjunction with an exporter for storing text in exported objects. How would I go about doing this?

I understand Blender has support for adding individual custom flags to an object, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. This is for a game engine and I need to be able to write out dozens of flags and other information. Having to add and edit individual custom properties for every single flag rather than writing everything in a large text box is too time-consuming and not very helpful.

Comment: Yes, each object in blender can have as many custom properties as you like. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43785/adding-other-types-of-custom-properties or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123669/finding-the-source-for-api-defined-custom-properties Suggest add more details about your actual goal...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know how to be any more clear then I already am lol

I would like to know how to create a blank text field in Blender's UI similar in function to 3DSMax's User-Defined Properties feature.

Comment: Re edit: I'd suggest have a look into python dicts, read https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html#custom-properties and use a text file to create them... pretty straight forward I guess.

Comment: Hello, not everyone knows what 3Ds Max's "User Defined Properties" are. If you want specific help, could you define the exact behaviour you're after ?